# Shiny reactive table based on select boxes

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I have a data set that contains 2 columns as of now (which I will add to later). I want to be able to make the table change based on the selected inputs in the select boxes. I also want to have the option to use one or multiple select boxes at a time. For example, I want to see all the names with the age "20" displayed on the table. I dont know how to change the server portion to make my table reactive.
I also plan to add more data and widgets, so I need to be able to add more reactive filters.

```
l <- NULL
l$name <- c('b','e','d','b','b','d','e')
l$age <- c(20,20,21,21,20,22,22)
l <- as.data.frame(l)
l$name <- as.character(l$name)
l$age <- as.numeric(l$age)

ui <-  fluidPage(
  titlePanel("example"),
 
  
  
   selectInput( "age2", 
                  " Select Age", 
                  choices = c("SELECT", unique(l$age))), 

   selectInput( "name2", 
                  " Select name", 
                  choices = c("SELECT", unique(l$name))),

  
 mainPanel(ui <- 
           dataTableOutput("Table1")
          
          ),

      )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 

  
 output$Table1 <- renderDataTable(l, options = list(pageLength = 10))
  


}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should remember to do is to make your data reactive with the `reactive` function. Any data you plan on using and for it to be reactive, wrap it in the reactive function.

Notes: The `{{value}}` allows you to access the value passed from the function.

Once you wrap the l dataframe in reactive, you use parenthesis around the value anywhere you use it.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

l <- NULL
l$name <- c('b','e','d','b','b','d','e')
l$age <- c(20,20,21,21,20,22,22)
l <- as.data.frame(l)
l$name <- as.character(l$name)
l$age <- as.numeric(l$age)

df <- function(data, ...) {

  map2_dfr(...names(), seq_along(...names()), \(x,y) {
    
    data <<- data |> 
      filter(.data[[x]] %in% ...elt(y) )
  }) 
  
  
  return(data)

} 
  
  
  return(data |> unique())

}

ui <-  fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("example"),
  
  
  
  selectInput( "age2", 
               " Select Age", 
               choices = c(unique(l$age))), 
  
  selectInput( "name2", 
               " Select name", 
               choices = c(unique(l$name))),
  
  
  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("Table1"),
    verbatimTextOutput("text")
            
  ),
  

  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  data <- reactive(l)

  output$Table1 <- DT::renderDataTable(df(data(), input$age2, input$name2))
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: How would I implement 20 more columns? Would I have to do the if else statement for everyone? thank you for your help.

Comment: I updated the function for large column arguments. You're basically mapping over the names and filtering the data. `<<-` allows you to access data outside of the score of map function

Comment: Thats really helpful thank you. So say if I add another column such as "favcolor" i would do  map2_dfr(...names(), seq_along(...names(), seq_along(...favcolor()), \(x,y) ?

Comment: No it loops over every argument you supply it, so you don't need to alter the function at all

Comment: Im getting the error "  <text>:19:1: unexpected '}'
18: }
19: }